# Checking the version of an ipython library from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, ipython, version, libraries, anaconda

I'm using iPython from the Anaconda distribution and I want to know how to check the version of some of the libraries from Terminal (using Mac), for example scikit_learn, but don't know the commands...

could someone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With anaconda, you can find information about the version with the following command:

```
conda list <package name>
```

for instance:

```
conda list scipy
```

will return (on my system, from my default environment)

```
# packages in environment at /Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3:
#
scipy                     0.15.1               np19py34_0
```

for your specific question, use:

```
conda list scikit-learn
```

To find what versions are available for your system, use:

```
conda info scikit-learn
```

if you find that you need to update the library, first update conda

```
conda update conda
```

then, updating anaconda will update all your libraries (those installed by conda)

```
conda update anaconda
```

if you only want to update this specific library (but you may have to deal with dependencies)

```
conda update -n <environment name> scikit_learn
```

If you ever need to revert to a previous version:
first find out the history of the versions you updated to

```
conda list -r scikit-learn
```

then choose the revision you want to revert to (the number will be from the list given by the command above):

```
conda install --revision=4 scikit-learn
```